# How to emit from Flux onComplete

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to implement something similar to Akka Streams statefulMapConcat... Basically I have a Flux of scores something like this:

`Score(LocalDate date, Integer score)`

I want to take these in and emit one aggregate per day:

`ScoreAggregate(LocalDate date, Integer scoreCount, Integer totalScore)`

So I've got an aggregator that keeps some internal state that I set up before processing, and I want to flatmap over that aggregator which returns a Mono. The aggregator will only emit a Mono with a value if the date changes so you only get one per day.

```
ScoreAggregator aggregator = ...

Flux<Score> scoreFlux = ...

scoreFlux.flatMap(aggregator::addScore)
```

So my question is... how do I emit a final element when the `scoreFlux` completes? The aggregator will have some data for the final day that hasn't been emitted yet and I need to get that sent.

Comment: I may not understand fully, but could you just use `concatWith()` after the flatmap call and add the other publisher you want?

Comment: Ahhh... yeah. Here's what I'm doing: .concatWith(Flux.defer(aggregator::onComplete)) where the onComplete() method will return a Mono of the final aggregate

Comment: Yup, precisely - that should work, as `defer()` makes sure it doesn't execute ahead of time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing the comment as an answer just so this doesn't show as unanswered:

> So my question is... how do I emit a final element when the scoreFlux completes?

You can simply use `concatWith()` to concatenate the publisher you want after your original flux completes. If you only want that to be *evaluated* when the original publisher completes, make sure you wrap it up in `Mono.defer()`, which will prevent the pre-emptive execution.